# Mod_pagespeed is indexing my website?

Tags: linux, mod-pagespeed

I recently installed mod_pagespeed on my linux server.

today i noticed that the raw_log contains alot of GET  from my own servers Ip.
Why is it doing that?

```
XX.XX.XX.112 - - [08/Aug/2015:15:04:16 +0200] "GET /img/p/da-default-large_default.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 7018 "http://www.XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-comprehensivedefectivematerialretention-bl2x220c-g7-foundationcare-svc.html" "Serf/1.1.0 mod_pagespeed/1.9.32.4-7251"

XX.XX.XX.112 - - [08/Aug/2015:15:04:06 +0200] "GET /9558-home_default/samsung-s7580-galaxy-trend-plus-pure-white-eu.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 7027 "http://XXXXX/sph/" "Serf/1.1.0 mod_pagespeed/1.9.32.4-7251"

XX.XX.XX.112 - - [08/Aug/2015:16:35:58 +0200] "GET /themes/css/modules/blockpermanentlinks/img/arrow_right_2.png HTTP/1.1" 302 - "http://www.XXXX/Xknive/" "Serf/1.1.0 mod_pagespeed/1.9.32.4-7251"

XX.XX.XX.112 - - [08/Aug/2015:16:35:58 +0200] "GET /themes/img/jquery/uniform/bg-input.png HTTP/1.1" 302 - "http://www.XXXX/knive/" "Serf/1.1.0 mod_pagespeed/1.9.32.4-7251"
```

Comment: Just a supposition: the clients who browse the servers in the log ask the files to your server because you are faster than them; who develops mod_pagespeed? Google

Comment: Yes Google , hmm i didnt know that conpressing funktions etc.. will do that manually , i thougt it Will do it In Real time when a visiter visit the website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to optimize the resources (images, js, css, etc.) on your page, mod_pagespeed must first fetch them. By default, it uses loopback HTTP fetches to your server to do this, which is what you are seeing in your logs.

If your setup allows it, you can configure mod_pagespeed to load the resources from disk, instead of HTTP, using the [LoadFromFile option](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/domains#ModPagespeedLoadFromFile).

Comment: That is something i Can use.  Thanks alot for this tip